# Why did an answer stating reasons for the questions eventual deletion get deleted & earn negative reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions, up-votes

I answered to the question below pointing out the exact reasons why the question got put on hold and deleted eventually.

My answer had **10 upvote** events, 2 downvote events and a comment with the same sentiments, agreeing with my answer.
I even flagged the question citing said reasons.

My confusion is: why did my apparently correct assessment get deleted and resulted in negative reputation for me (apparently higher than what I gained from the answer)?

The question in question (;

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/117440/does-wearing-a-rolex-help-with-ones-career-progression

Comment: People feel welcome to come here and have the rules and norms of the community explained., so, why the down votes?

Comment: @BenMz, a downvote on a question on meta typically just means "I disagree with your position on this", not "This is a terrible attempt at a question and should be tarred, feathered & boiled alive".

Comment: @brhans yeah but my question is not an opinion or position ! I actually was asking for clarification about stackexchange and its procedures (in this case the negative reputation from a deleted answer to a question that got deleted in agreement with my stated opinion). As Ben Mz said, it was more a cry for help than an outburst of my controversial stand on something. I don't understand the downvotes either,sorry. How can one even disagree with an honest, clear cut question ? Very confusing...maybe I should put this into a question and see how the votes go (;

Answer (score 9):

Please don't use answers to explain why a question should be closed; that's what close votes or flagging to close is for (depending on your reputation).

The question was deleted because it had a score of -6 and was closed as being primarily opinion-based - you flagged it to be closed as such and you said that in your answer:

> Well, it may help to be punctual.
>
> Other than that, this question can only be answered by opinions and is heavily dependent on subjective views, differing between personalities, countries and cultures.

The score of your answer was half what you seem to remember, having received only five upvotes and one downvote:

[image: Screenshot of answer to a deleted question.]

When a question is deleted, so too are the answers. All reputation associated with votes on those posts is reset. You would have earned a total of 48 reputation and then had it removed when the question was deleted.

Comment: ah, thanks a lot for clearing that up. regarding the votes, I checked before I posted this question and in the event list it says 10x +10 up and 2x -2 down. Oddly different to the summary of the events: +20+30-2 Sorry for the confusion, looks like I'm reading something wrong (I'm fairly new to stackexchange).

Comment: Seems like there may be an odd duplication error in the notifications, considering it's exactly double. Could you add a screenshot of it to your question if you can still see it?

Comment: it's gone now after I refreshed the page from earlier.stating 50-2 (;

Comment: Ah, OK! Sorry about the confusion! If you see it happen again, let me know and we can look into it. :)

Comment: will do, thanks a lot!